# Efficient implementation of a sequence of matrix-vector products / specific "tensor"-matrix product

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a special algorithm where as one of the lasts steps I need to carry out a multiplication of a 3-D array with a 2-D array such that each matrix-slice of the 3-D array is multiplied wich each column of the 2-D array. In other words, if, say `A` is an `N x N x N` matrix and `B` is an `N x N` matrix, I need to compute a matrix `C` of size `N x N` where `C(:,i) = A(:,:,i)*B(:,i);`.

The naive way to implement this is a loop, i.e.,

```
C = zeros(N,N);
for i = 1:N
    C(:,i) = A(:,:,i)*B(:,i);
end
```

However, loops aren't the fastest in Matlab and should be avoided. I'm looking for faster ways of doing this. Right now, what I do is to use the fact that (now Mathjax would be great!):

> [A1 b1, A2 b2, ..., AN bN] = [A1, A2, ..., AN]*blkdiag(b1,b2,...,bN)

This allows to get rid of the loop, however, we have to create a block-diagonal matrix of size `N^2 x N`. I'm making it via `sparse` to be efficient, i.e., like this:

```
A_long = reshape(A,N,N^2);
b_cell = mat2cell(B,N,ones(1,N)); % convert matrix to cell array of vectors
b_cell{1} = sparse(b_cell{1});    % make first element sparse, this is enough to trigger blkdiag into sparse mode
B_blk = blkdiag(b_cell{:});
C = A_long*B_blk;
```

According to my benchmarks, this approach is faster than the loop by a factor of around two (for large N), despite the necessary preparations (the multiplication alone is 3 to 4-fold faster than the loop).

Here is a quick benchmark I did, varying the problem size `N` and measuring the time for the loop and the alternative approach (with and without the preparation steps). For large `N` the speedup is around 2...2.5.

[image: Benchmarking result]

Still, this looks awfully complicated to me. Is there a simpler or better way to achieve this? This looks like it's a quite generic/standard problem so I could imagine that solutions are around, I just don't know what to search for really.

P.S.: `blkdiag(A1,...,AN)*B` is an obvious alternative but here the block diagonal is already `N^2 x N^2` so I don't think it can be better than what I did.

**edit**: Thanks to everyone for commenting! I have carried out a new benchmark on a Matlab R2016b. Unfortunately, I do not have both versions on the same computer so we cannot compare the absolute numbers but the relative comparison is still interesting, since it has changed a bit. Here it is:

[image: New benchmark on R2016b]

And here is a zoom on the high-N area:

[image: New benchmark on R2016b, zoom]

Couple of observations:

- SumRepDot is the solution proposed by Divakar, namely, to use `squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3,1,2])),2))` which on R2016b simplifies to `squeeze(sum(A.*permute(B,[3,1,2]),2))`. It is faster than the loop for high `N` by a factor of around 1.2...1.4.
- The loop is still "slow" in a sense that the multiplication with the sparse block diagonal matrix is much faster.
- For the latter, the preparation overhead seems to become negligible for high `N` which makes it overall a factor of 3...4 faster than the loop. This is a nice result.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?  The more recent versions of MATLAB (circa R2015b) have an improved JIT so loops are actually now very competitive.

Comment: Good point, this was tested on a R2014b if I'm not mistaken. I'll try and see if I can repeat the test on a more recent one.

Comment: Please do :) And let us know... btw, if it helps I don't see a more efficient way of doing that without block diagonalization.  That was actually the approach I was going to suggest.  Try it with a loop on a more recent MATLAB version and let us know what timing results you get.

Comment: I've also including more relevant tags so [@Divakar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) will hopefully come across your post and help.  He is known around here for his vectorization skills.

Comment: You could do - `squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3,1,2])),2))`, but it would depend on their sizes if this is any better, specifically if the last dim is a long one.

Comment: @Divakar That's a good point.  Florian, please include the code you used to generate the data which gave those timing results.

Comment: @rayryeng For times like these, I wish we had [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) in MATLAB.

Comment: @Divakar I agree. I just recently learned how to use that function... It's the best function in numpy.

Comment: @Divakar: I thought about something like that too (though your version is much more compact than what I had in mind) but was afraid that ditching matrix multiplication in favor of sum would do more harm than good. I'll definitely include it in the benchmark though and paste my results as soon as I get hold of a more recent Matlab version. It's a pity Matlab doesn't support this natively since it could be nicely optimized, like via the einsum you suggested. Nice to know this exists in numpy.

Comment: @Divakar, @rayryeng: I have added a new benchmark. It seems the sparse block diagonal still wins over loops on R2016b. The solution proposed by Divakar beats the loop as well for high `N` but by a smaller factor. Thanks to everyone so far for commenting!

Comment: Honestly I don't think you can squeeze any more performance. The timing also seems pretty fast for high `N`. I say just stick with what you're comfortable with.