# How efficiently multiply two sequences of matrixes in Matlab without loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, gpu

I have two matrix group

```
A1, A2... Ai  N x K
B1, B2... Bi  K x M
```

and I wanna get matrix `C = [A1 * B1; A2 * B2; ... Ai * Bi];`
Can it be done in Matlab without loop? 
Can I efficiently use GPU for this operation?

Comment: `C=A.*B`. But seems that `A` and `B` are not at same length...

Comment: A1, A2...Ai are matrixes so the task is in matrix multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution (since you could argue that `cellfun` kind of loops implicitly as well: Use the fact that

> [A1*B1, A2*B2, ..., Ai*Bi] = [A1, A2, ..., Ai] * blkdiag(B1, B2, ..., Bi)

(alternatively, `blkdiag(A1,...,Ai)*[B1,...,Bi]`).

If the number of marices (i) is fixed, you can directly write it this way. If not and you have them, say in a 3-D matrix where `Ai = A(:,:,i)` and `Bi = B(:,:,i)` such that `A` is `N x K x i` and `B` is `K x M x i`then you can do

```
A = reshape(A,N,K*i);
B = mat2cell(B,K,M*ones(1,i));
B{1} = sparse(B{1}); % make one sparse to trigger blkdiag into sparse mode
C = A*blkdiag(B{:});
```

Comment: `blkdiag` seems usefull function for this purpose, but will it eat memory for big `i` as square time or such operation as `[A1, A2, ..., Ai] * blkdiag(B1, B2, ..., Bi)` is optimized in matlab?

Comment: And can I avoid loop if I have matrix `A` with size `(N * i) x K` and `B`  with size  `K x (M * i)`?

Comment: The matrix `blkdiag(B1,B2,...,Bi)` is `K*i x M*i` so you would expect it to eat a lot of memory. This is why I have used `sparse` in my definition so that all the zeros do not take any memory at all and the multiplication remains efficient. Sparse comes with some overhead but it shouldn't be worse than a factor of two. Try it out and see how it works for you.

Comment: I recently ran into a similar problem, which is the special case of yours for `K=N` and `M=1`. In this case the sparse block diagonal was quite efficient. You can see some benchmarks here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898122/efficient-implementation-of-a-sequence-of-matrix-vector-products-specific-ten

Comment: `M ~= 1` in my case. And unfortunately there is no `mat2cell` function for run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu, so 2 variant cannot be efficiently used in gpu, can it?

Comment: Hmmm, if you run it on a GPU the question is if there is an efficient way to construct a sparse block diagonal matrix. Not that I know of but I'm not sure. The cell arrays are not really crucial here, they were just used as a trick for simple construction. Anyways, if you have access to hardware parallelization, the for loop might not be that bad, after all, the whole loop can be parallelized. Try using `parfor` maybe?

Comment: `parfor` is for CPU, but I try to use GPU for many similar independent tasks acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Use [pagefun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) for the GPU, it uses batch operations that are much faster than looping.